# Visual Studio 2010/2012 crashes when adding service/web reference

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-services, visual-studio-2012, wsdl

in a project I am working on, I need to use a java webservice that has been created by another company. Each time I try to reference the "wsdl" of this webservice, in order to import all the information, my Visual Studio crashes. This happens in VS 2010, VS2012, and also adding service reference, or web reference doesn't change anything.

Has this occured to anybody else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason Visual Studio was crashing, was that the WSDL did contain a circular reference. Once this had been fixed, I managed to import the WSDL correctly.

This webpage might talk about this problem, though it seems quite old.

[explanation on microsoft website](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/356916/adding-web-service-reference-with-a-recursive-type-with-an-unbounded-choice-crashes-vs-2005-2008)